# How can I suppress warnings in SublimeLinter for mixed spaces/tabs in comments?

Tags: comments, sublimetext3, jshint, suppress-warnings, sublimelinter

Here is a link to a screenshot of the warnings:

[image: screenshot]

I would like to be able to use the "cmd+/" shortcut to quickly comment out sections of code.  Whenever I do, I get a bunch of space/tab mixing errors.  I am required to use tabs for coding standards, but it seems Sublime 3 forces spaces for the comments.  I also enjoy the error checking for space/tab mixing through non-commented code, so I would like to leave that intact if possible.

Is there a way to modify Sublime's settings to change the commenting shorcuts functionality or is there a way to modify SublimeLinter-jshint's settings to ignore these warnings?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to remove the space from after the `//`. Open your `Packages` folder via `Preferences -> Browse Packages...` and create a folder called `JavaScript`. I assume you're on OS X, so the full path to the folder is `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`. Next, create a new file in Sublime with the following contents:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Comments</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.js, source.json</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>shellVariables</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>//</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START_2</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>/*</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_END_2</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>*/</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>A67A8BD9-A951-406F-9175-018DD4B52FD1</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and save it in the `Packages/JavaScript` folder as `Comments.tmPreferences`. You'll notice that the `TM_COMMENT_START` value is `//`, whereas in the original it's `//`. Restart Sublime, and now when you're editing JavaScript or JSON files and hit <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> your code will be commented out without the addition of a space.

Comment: This wasn't the exact solution, but pointed me in the right direction.  For some reason, it did nothing when I put all this information in a Comments.tmPreferences file.

I downloaded a version of JavaScript.tmLanguage (https://github.com/drowne/Better-JavaScript-Sublime/blob/master/JavaScript.tmLanguage) and placed it in the same directory as the code above and that worked beautifully.  Thanks for the assistance.